# 'Extended Secondary Dominant Chords'?

Tags: chord-theory, terminology

Was asked about secondary dominants recently. Also about secondary extended dominants.

From a bit of research, it seems there are two views on what the latter are. Could be *extended* (dominant) chords - as in 9ths, 11ths, 13ths, with/out alterations. Usually in root position, with notes expanding past the octave. Or - dominant chords which move to another dominant , as in key C, the A7 that moves to D7.

I can understand *extended chords* as such, and also *extended chord* **sequences**, which the second definition nods towards. but the two definitions just don't appear to align.

I guess in the latter, key C, A7 going to Dm7 wouldn't qualify as an extended secondary (secondary extended?) chord. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we know what a Secondary Dominant is.  There seems to be an alternative name - Extended Dominant.  Which is confusing, due to the more usual meaning of an Extended chord - 9ths and 13ths etc.   So better to stick with Secondary Dominant I think!

I've never heard of an Extended Secondary Dominant.  The references I can find to that term are queries rather than definitions.  So I guess we can't count it as a standard term.  If someone uses it, check what HE thinks it means!

An associated question.  In Dm7, G7, C is the first chord a Secondary Dominant?  Or must it be D7, G7, C to qualify?     If Bm7b5, E7, Am7, Dm7, G7, C (or any other mix of minor and major 7 chords) isn't a string of Secondary Dominants, it's something darn close! Maybe no leading note and tritone, but a definite dominant function.   So what do we call it?

Comment: In regards to your last sentence, I would just call it a circle of fifths. A "secondary" (or "applied") dominant, in my opinion, specifically suggests chromaticism that makes it a dominant-functioning chord. Thus the only true secondary dominant in your final sentence is the E7.

Comment: I would tend to agree; when I read the title, I interpreted it as chord extensions on dominants that happen to also serve the role of secondary dominant in a key center.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already have the answer in your question.

In something like `C: A7 D7 G7 C` the secondary dominant "extend" back in the progression, but this kind of thing has a clear name: *harmonic sequence*.

Some people use the term *backcycling*.

Both just seem to be terms people have coined, because they don't know a (basic) term like harmonic sequence.

So, someone seems to be skipping over two existing terms and coining a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Berklee College of Music uses the term "Extended Dominants" in their harmony curriculum.

Extended Dominants: A series of dominants without a direct key relationship, each one resolving down a fifth to the next.

source: https://college.berklee.edu/core/glossary.html

Comment: So, in key C, where D7 is present, but *doesn't* go directly to G/G7, that D7 *won't* be an 'extended dominant'?

Comment: Are you thinking of something like the A section to Take The A Train? I would not call that D7 an extended dominant or a secondary dominant, but some do call it a secondary dominant. Unless it sounds like it "wants" to resolve down a 5th or half step, I just call it "II7"